# What is the meaning of 事情的经过 in 而事情的经过对记忆几乎没有影响?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

我们对事物的记忆仅在高峰和结尾，而事情的经过对记忆几乎没有影响。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 17.

What is the meaning of 事情的经过?

I am at this point:

而(and)事情的经过(?)对(towards)记忆(memory)几乎(almost)没有(not have)影响(effect)

According to dictionaries 事情 means thing or matter, while 经过 means either process, course as noun or to pass as verb etc. It has several meanins.

How to make the sentence above have sense?

Comment: What I understand is that, it's simply saying that we mainly remember the main scenes and events in the story （事情的经过对记忆几乎没有影响）, but usually could not remember the details of the process

Answer (score 2):

我们对事物的记忆仅在高峰和结尾，
Our memory of things is (usually) of the main points and the endings,
而事情的经过对记忆几乎没有影响。
but the passage, the process to those (main points and the endings) is almost never remembered.

Answer (score 1):

事情的经过 - the process/course of the matter...